# Running multiple hive queries using tHiveRow component in Talend

Tags: hadoop, hive, talend

Hi i want to tun multiple hive queries through a single component. Through tHiveRow i'm able to run single query but unable to run multiple queries at a time.

I know that we can run multiple sql queries after going through the following link  http://www.vikramtakkar.com/2013/05/example-to-execute-multiple-sql-queries.html

But any one has any idea as how to run multiple queries?

Comment: did you tried writing multiple statements with semicolon separation..like below "analyze table1;
analyze table2;
analyze table3;" in thiveRow

Comment: Yes that was the first thing i tried but was getting compilation errors

Answer (score 2):

Your link reference shows a MySQL connection... this says nothing about the Hive JDBC driver capabilities, since running multiple statements in one JDBC statement is a driver specific feature!

To run multiple queries:
Start with a **tFixedFlowInput** component. Configure one String column and choose table input option; you will get a table with one column. Each line, you add, will be one Hive statement. Now connect it with a tHiveRow component and use the column of the ingoing flow in the SQL textarea by **<flowName>.<columnName> e.g.: row1.sqlStatement** (if the String column in your tFixedFlowInput has the name "sqlStatement" and the connection between the tFixedFlowInput and the tHiveRow component is called "row1").

Comment: Not working, throwing me this error while following your solution.Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 extraneous input ';' expecting EOF near '<EOF>'
[ERROR]: staging.newcomp_0_1.newComp - tHiveRow_2 - Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:20 extraneous input ';' expecting EOF near '<EOF>'

Comment: A JDBC SQL statement does not end with a ";" (semicolon) - it should work without. just remove it.

Comment: With the same subjob how can i run multiple queries if i have multiple columns in tfixedflowinput? if i iterate my tfixedflowinput over thiverow then what should i put in thiverow query? tfixedflowinput gives out only two global variables error_message and nb_lines which can be used as a query

Comment: Please create another question, so that everbody with Talend know-how can help you.