# How to run multiple hive queries in tHiveRow in Talend latest versions

Tags: hive, talend

[image]

I'm using talend 6.2.1 version. Trying to run multiple hive queries in `tHiveRow`, but it simply not allowing me to do so if I separate my queries with a ";".

I have tried with `tForEach`, but there is a limitation to it as we cannot include a value greater than 130 characters.

So, I turned to `tFixedFlowInput` but iterative run for multiple queries seems not possible here.

I followed this [Running multiple hive queries using tHiveRow component in Talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899060/running-multiple-hive-queries-using-thiverow-component-in-talend/36948581?noredirect=1#comment81446542_36948581)

Can anybody help me achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by saving the hive script in a text file. Now read the textfile with row delimiter as ";" and feild delimiter as something that is not used in the entire script (cedilla or $). Schema of this file will have only one column(say query)

Now connect tfileinputDelimite--row1-->thiverow.  In thiverow query box write row1.query

That's it, it has woked for me .try.

Comment: thanks pal, ill try this. Hope this works for me too.